# Use condition in the Qt Creator designer

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm pretty new to Qt, and I can't find an answer to very basic question:
is it possible to use conditions when using the ui designer?
for example, that if a var x is set to true widget 1 will be displayed, otherwise widget b will be displayed in the same area?
I know how to do it in the code but wondered if it possible using the design tool...

Comment: Are you working with a QWidgets application or a Qt Quick application?

Comment: I'm using QWidget application.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is not a way to do it using the designer in a QWidgets application, though I have to admit I never really tried to do that.  In a Qt Quick QML application you can probably use a binding on the visible property to hide/show the desired item.